# Replace the product name by the Sku in the order received page

Tags: php, woocommerce

Using Woocommerce, I would like to add the SKU instead of the product name in the thank you page and order pages like in Order received (thankyou) and Order pay pages.

I use the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter hook like in [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888642/replace-the-product-name-by-the-sku-in-my-account-view-order-pages), but it works only My account > View order pages.
I have also tried to use `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` filter hook, but it doesn't work.

Can I know the correct complete code to add to `function.php` to be able to replace the product name by the SKU in Order received (thankyou) and Order pay pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the product name by the SKU on Order received, Order pay *(and my account Order view)* pages, you need to use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_sku_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_sku_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); 
        if( $sku = $product->get_sku() )
            $item_name = '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '" class="product-sku">' . __( "Product ", "woocommerce") . $sku . '</a>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Related: [Woocommerce conditional tags reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-11)

Comment: Again thank you very much. I was close to the correct code but still have a missing part of the code. Thank you for your support.